# Typescript - Enum key values as union types

Tags: typescript, enums, union-types

i have put [this code in the TS playground too, click here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAggcgSQLIwDIGUoG8BQUoDCMAKlALxQDkAxgIYAulANHlKggPJzlUA2AlgHsQzVgAUYAJUkdSFSgAdaAJ2WDGLfOgASUgNI9KAZwAWKgNaitcGAlSGjIWv16UcAXxw5%20IesGUAZrTUwFD8AEK0RsAwIPwQtLzYrE4QwABcUEb0yj4A5ppQeaAAJv6ZlAm8wJRQAD5UAcBVNawA7i4lmQBGgoLVtCAeXj5%20gcGh-OhmyuZQwAAefiAlRmGR0bHxicn4CQsA%20nkuvEaZ4BDd-sPevv5BIWFiKmr080ulaxFRMXFVu1AOiA8pksFBWPhqsD6CZMgBGABMAAZCvgwHF6BVqBA3PhPJ4cAB6QlQAAiXAAolAOAA3fxtXL0ej5KAKNQKfz0ACegJMoHeyxKLO6P1Z7LWHRh1Ig-HotzGD0m6CcLgFn2lsoAPN9Nn9EkwqMUVv5KAA%20AFGsrKCp85QJBQmNRCvxuAmje4TMJbKprXD4QbbU6giFQYlkylQCkXKA0xJgYBrKJQczALkhsNiClwUkIOAAcUBtB59EEYTuygU-QYoTZgg5yjLCs9sd48agIuiUGEUBhoVAkGTqZDAG0UzyfLBECgMABdTI636B1juQoZrM5-OF4ul4pvKMDlvxxNrdFCEA9rkctYACiM8RcKh7pdHqbLk%20QaHQM-bYDeAUEDYBOi1DMt2SjKLQEAAJSsLu3qJJk14BlUeipuklACMIzBdgooEgGcUCDFyUHkOaNKCPwJQeEAA), hope it helps.

### How get the Enum key values as union types (ie for function param)

Like i have done in the `animals` object using `key in` to get the key as the `enum ANIMALS values` i cannot find a way to do the same but like union types for the function param `animalKey`.
to get the something like `'cat' | 'lion' | 'parrot' | 'shark' | 'snail'`.

Any help would be much appreciated

```js
enum ANIMALS {
  CAT = 'cat',
  LION = 'lion',
  PARROT = 'parrot',
  SHARK = 'shark',
  SNAIL = 'snail'
}

interface iBaseAnimal {
  name: string,
  gender: 'male' | 'female'
  wild: boolean
}

interface iShark extends iBaseAnimal {
  max_gills: number
}

interface iParrot extends iBaseAnimal {
  wing: { 
    length: 120,
    unit: 'cm'
  }
}

// DONE Overwritting property when extending base props with Omit
interface iSnail extends Omit<iBaseAnimal, 'gender'> {
  gender: 'hermaphrodite'
}

interface iAnimals {
  animals: {
    // DONE Enum values as key
    // PENDING way to interpolate proper interface value base on the enum key
    [key in ANIMALS]: iBaseAnimal
  },
  // PENDING way to get Enum values as union types (similar to [key in ANIMALS] but for function param)
  getAnimal: (animalKey:'lion', options: any) => void
}
```

Comment: Enums already behave like a union of their values; therefore, does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/wQY9Vw) meet your needs? (Note that I changed the naming to be more conventional; you might want to make similar changes so as not to distract focus.)  If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution :

```
enum AnimalsEn {
    CAT = "cat",
    LION = "lion",
    PARROT = "parrot",
    SHARK = "shark",
    SNAIL = "snail"
}

interface iBaseAnimal {
    name: string,
    gender: "male" | "female"
    wild: boolean
}

type AnimalsExtends = {
    [AnimalsEn.SHARK]: {
        max_gills: number
    },

    [AnimalsEn.PARROT]: {
        wing: {
          length: 120,
          unit: "cm"
        }
    },

    [AnimalsEn.SNAIL]: {
        gender: "hermaphrodite"
    },
}

// Utility to merge two Definition B object properties shadowing A object properties
type $Merge<TA, TB> = Omit<TA, keyof TB> & TB;

// Getting the Base+Extended type of an Animal
type iAnimal<A extends AnimalsEn> =
    A extends keyof AnimalsExtends ?
        $Merge<iBaseAnimal, AnimalsExtends[A]> :
        iBaseAnimal;


interface iAnimals {
    animals: {
      // PENDING way to interpolate proper interface value base on the enum key
      [key in AnimalsEn]: iAnimal<key> // just using utility to get the right Type
    },
    // Enum as a type ARE union of their posibles values
    getAnimal: (animalKey: AnimalsEn, options: any) => void
}
```

You can improve this pattern as follow espacialy usefull if you plan to add/remove animal types later:

```
// a type for AnyAnimal
type AnyAnimal = { [key in AnimalsEn]: iAnimal<key> }[AnimalsEn];

// adding a type property on the finals interfaces
// this way you could easily discriminate animals by their type, refinement works very well with this
type iAnimal<A extends AnimalsEn> =
    (A extends keyof AnimalsExtends ?
        $Merge<iBaseAnimal, AnimalsExtends[A]> :
        iBaseAnimal) & { type: A };

// you could use it very smoothly now : 

export class NotExhaustiveError extends Error {
    constructor (value: never) {
        super(`Not allowed Value[${value}]`);
    }
}

function doingSomethingWith(animal: AnyAnimal) {
    // here animal is like 
    // {
    //     type: AnimalsEn,
    //     gender: "male" | "female" | "hermaphrodite";
    //     name: string,
    //     wild: boolean,
    // }
    const type = animal.type;
    switch (type) {
        case AnimalsEn.CAT: // here is a cat!
            break;
        case AnimalsEn.LION: // here is a lion!
            break;
        case AnimalsEn.PARROT: // here is a parrot!
            break;
        case AnimalsEn.SHARK: // here is a shark!
            break;
        case AnimalsEn.SNAIL: // here is a snail!
            break;
        default: // this will *throw* at *compile* time if you forgot to handle a case before
            throw new NotExhaustiveError(type);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello Romain, this is definetly an awesome workaround, its not fully automaticaly but i love the way to have the AnimalsExtends clean to manage the exceptions.

Comment: you're welcome, some improvement and thoughts added. You could also avoid using enum and replace it by a type like `type AnimalsEn = keyof AnimalsExtends` but you'll have to replace all uses of AnimalsEn.XXX by the direct value...